# Why does this LEFT JOIN to a calendar table return 0 results?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a calendar table `cal` set up that reaches from the first day of a month to the last day of a month with an interval of one hour, like so:

```
   bucket_start     |     bucket_end      
--------------------+---------------------
2013-09-01 00:00:00 | 2013-09-01 00:59:59
2013-09-01 01:00:00 | 2013-09-01 01:59:59
2013-09-01 02:00:00 | 2013-09-01 02:59:59
. . .
2013-09-30 21:00:00 | 2013-09-30 21:59:59
2013-09-30 22:00:00 | 2013-09-30 22:59:59
2013-09-30 23:00:00 | 2013-09-30 23:59:59
```

I have another table `t` that holds data like so

```
    id    |        when         |  fk  |
----------+-----------------------------
181207367 | 2013-09-16 17:02:50 |  211 |
181207368 | 2013-09-16 17:04:50 |  211 |
181207369 | 2013-09-16 17:06:50 |  211 |
181207370 | 2013-09-16 17:08:50 |  211 |
181207371 | 2013-09-16 17:10:50 |  211 |
181207372 | 2013-09-16 17:12:50 |  211 |
181207373 | 2013-09-16 17:14:50 |  211 |
181207374 | 2013-09-16 17:16:50 |  211 |
181207375 | 2013-09-16 17:18:50 |  211 |
181207376 | 2013-09-16 17:20:50 |  211 |
. . .
```

What I want to achieve is a result that gives me the counts of how many rows in `t` do I have in the given hour of `cal`, like so:

```
   bucket_start     |     bucket_end      | cnt |
--------------------+----------------------------
2013-09-01 00:00:00 | 2013-09-01 00:59:59 |  5  |
2013-09-01 01:00:00 | 2013-09-01 01:59:59 | 12  |
2013-09-01 02:00:00 | 2013-09-01 02:59:59 |  0  |
. . .
2013-09-30 21:00:00 | 2013-09-30 21:59:59 |  9  |
2013-09-30 22:00:00 | 2013-09-30 22:59:59 |  5  |
2013-09-30 23:00:00 | 2013-09-30 23:59:59 |  0  |
```

So I wrote the following query:

```
  SELECT cal.bucket_start, cal.bucket_end, COUNT(t.id) cnt
    FROM cal LEFT JOIN t on t.when BETWEEN cal.bucket_start AND cal.bucket_end
   WHERE t.fk = 211
GROUP BY cal.bucket_start, cal.bucket_end;
```

This basically works if there is at least one data row in `t` to match the bucket span. However if there isn't the result row gets omitted, which I don't get since I'm using `LEFT JOIN` here. What am I missing?

Comment: Are you sure? It looks like this should work, but you didn't add an `ORDER BY` clause, which means the database can hussle the records. Maybe they are further down the results.

Comment: Your query should work. As a work-around, you could try `select c.bucket_start, c.bucket_end, (select count(*) from t where t.when between c.bucket_start and c.bucket_end) as cnt from cal c`.

Comment: Yes, I tried the workaround as well, and this gives me the correct results. In addition I restrict the data that gets fetched from `t` with a `WHERE` clause on a foreign key, which I didn't mention. Can this be of any influence?

Comment: Is the cal table just to do the grouping by hour? You could always do `select date_trunc('hour', t.when), count(*) from t group by 1`, and join to `generate_series()` to fill in the gaps. That seems like it'd be easier to reason about than the join.

Comment: if your where clause references t then that could filter out your rows with 0. Can you provide the full query?

Comment: @Vapire _In addition I restrict the data that gets fetched from t with a WHERE clause_ Yes that turns the `left join` into an `inner join`. That should be mentioned. The solution is to move the condition in the where clause to the join condition

Comment: I updated the query with the `WHERE` clause. And now I feel stupid :-) Of course the query gets restricted through the where clause first before applying the join...

Comment: The query I'm looking at doesn't have a where clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This basically works if there is at least one data row in t to match the bucket span. However if there isn't the result row gets omitted, which I don't get since I'm using LEFT JOIN here.

No, that just works. The key is in a comment you made . . .

> In addition I restrict the data that gets fetched from t with a WHERE clause on a foreign key, which I didn't mention. Can this be of any influence?

Sure, and that's the problem. In SQL, the WHERE clause is evaluated *after* the dbms builds a working table from all the table constructors, including joins, in the FROM clause.

You *might* get the result set you want by moving the conditions that are now in the WHERE clause into the join condition. For example, this query will return all 720 rows, but . . .

```
with cal as (
select 
  generate_series(timestamp '2013-09-01 00:00:00', timestamp '2013-09-30 23:59:59', interval '1 hour') bucket_start,
  generate_series(timestamp '2013-09-01 00:59:59', timestamp '2013-09-30 23:59:59', interval '1 hour') bucket_end
), 
t as (
select 181207367 as id, timestamp '2013-09-16 17:02:50' as when union all
select 181207368, '2013-09-16 17:04:50' union all
select 181207369, '2013-09-16 17:06:50' union all
select 181207370, '2013-09-16 17:08:50' union all
select 181207371, '2013-09-16 17:10:50' union all
select 181207372, '2013-09-16 17:12:50' union all
select 181207373, '2013-09-16 17:14:50' union all
select 181207374, '2013-09-16 17:16:50' union all
select 181207375, '2013-09-16 17:18:50' union all
select 181207376, '2013-09-16 17:20:50'
)
SELECT cal.bucket_start, cal.bucket_end, COUNT(t.id) cnt
FROM cal 
LEFT JOIN t on t.when 
  BETWEEN cal.bucket_start AND cal.bucket_end and t.id < 100
GROUP BY cal.bucket_start, cal.bucket_end
order by cal.bucket_start;
```

look at the count for the 17:00 hour bucket. It's zero. That's one of the effects of changing the join condition.

**A caution**

In most, if not all, SQL database management systems, 23:59:59 isn't the end of a bucket. They all (?) support microsecond precision in timestamps, and I'm pretty sure higher precision is the default for all of them.  So your query will omit from the count all rows having a time like 23:59:59.6675. PostgreSQL's default is six digits, as in values like 23:59:59.123456.

I think you're better off with a cal table like this (although for economy I've implemented it as a common table expression), and a join condition that implements a half open interval.

```
with cal as (
select 
  generate_series(timestamp '2013-09-01 00:00:00', timestamp '2013-09-30 23:00:00', interval '1 hour') bucket_start,
  generate_series(timestamp '2013-09-01 01:00:00', timestamp '2013-09-30 24:00:00', interval '1 hour') bucket_end
  --                                          Buckets end on the hour    ^^^^^^^^
)
, t as (
select 181207367 as id, timestamp '2013-09-16 17:02:50' as when union all
select 181207368, '2013-09-16 17:04:50' union all
select 181207369, '2013-09-16 17:06:50' union all
select 181207370, '2013-09-16 17:08:50' union all
select 181207371, '2013-09-16 17:10:50' union all
select 181207372, '2013-09-16 17:12:50' union all
select 181207373, '2013-09-16 17:14:50' union all
select 181207374, '2013-09-16 17:16:50' union all
select 181207375, '2013-09-16 17:18:50' union all
select 181207376, '2013-09-16 17:20:50' union all
select 181207377, '2013-09-16 17:59:59.66745'
)
SELECT cal.bucket_start, cal.bucket_end, COUNT(t.id) cnt
FROM cal 
LEFT JOIN t 
  ON t.when >= cal.bucket_start AND t.when < cal.bucket_end
  --       ^^^^                           ^^^
  -- Join condition is a half open interval, closed on the left,
  -- and open on the right.
GROUP BY cal.bucket_start, cal.bucket_end
ORDER BY cal.bucket_start;
```